# Clickhouse. Optimize table on cluster doesnt work properly

Tags: sql, database, replication, ddl, clickhouse

I have a cluster 2x2 v19.15.2.2 with replicated partitioned table.

```
select * from system.parts 

=> some_part_0_0_1, some_part_0_0_2 and etc.
```

shows me some unmerged parts.

[Doc says](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/misc/#misc_operations-optimize), that during call `optimize` all the parts will be merged, but after call such query

```
// current settings on each node 
optimize_throw_if_noop = 1 
replication_alter_partitions_sync = 2 

optimize table my_table on cluster my_cluster partition my_partition final
```

It just generate one more part and old parts doesnt merge.

What i am doing wrong ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select * from system.parts **WHERE active**

merge process (initiated by optimize) merges several old (active) parts into a new active part. Old parts (merged) became inactive and will be removed after 8 minutes (defending 8 minutes because CH does not use fsync by performance reason).

Comment: What if one of four replicas is down ? It says, that `There are 2 unfinished hosts (1 of them are currently active), they are going to execute the query in background.` Will it receive current query when its up ? How i can be sure ? Thanks.

Comment: It said by Distributed DDL. Actually Optimize query makes sense only at a table's leader. You cluster 2x2. So you have two leaders (one in each shard). That only live leader scheduled a merge in ZK and performed it by itself and put metainfo about newly merged part into ZK. When another replica in that shard became live it will read ZK and perform merge or download the new part (it depend of several factors, algorithm is quite large to explain it here).